# How do I add an Images folder to my FileWrapper

Tags: swift, xcode, document, filewrapper

I need a FileWrapper which contains a file and contains a folder.
The file is a single file, and the folder is used to write images to.

The folder also can contain some subfolders. I have a working code, but the issue is that when the Document gets saved, the folder gets re-written which deletes my images and subfolders.

I'm quite sure it has something to do with `func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper` but I need some help from somebody with more experience with FileWrappers.

### This is my code:

```
struct MyProject: FileDocument {
    var myFile: MyFile
    
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.myf] }

    init(myFile: MyFile = MyFile() {
        self.myFile = myFile
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let data = configuration.file.fileWrappers?["MYFProject"]?.regularFileContents else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        do {
            self.myFile = try decoder.decode(MyFile.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(myFile)
            
            let mainDirectory = FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [:])
            let myfWrapper = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
            let imagesWrapper = FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [:])
            let imageSubFolder = FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [:])
        
            for numberString in myFile.numbers {
                imageSubFolder.preferredFilename = numberString
                imagesWrapper.addFileWrapper(imageSubFolder)
            }
            
            myfWrapper.preferredFilename = "MYFProject"
            mainDirectory.addFileWrapper(myfWrapper)
            
            imagesWrapper.preferredFilename = "MYFImages"
            mainDirectory.addFileWrapper(imagesWrapper)
            
            return mainDirectory
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

### I use this path to write images to.

```
func getSubFolderImageFolder(documentPath: URL, subFolder: String) -> URL {
    let sfProjectPath = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("MYFImages").appendingPathComponent(subFolder)
    
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: sfProjectPath.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: sfProjectPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            return sfProjectPath
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    else {
        return sfProjectPath
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getSubFolderImageFolder` function is not going to work well with file wrappers. You must use the `FileWrapper` methods to create the folders and files in the file wrapper.

To add a subfolder to your images folder, create a directory file wrapper the same way you created the `imagesWrapper` folder for the images. Add the subfolder as a child of the images folder.

```
let imageSubFolder = FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [:])
imagesWrapper.addFileWrapper(imageSubFolder)
```

You must create a directory file wrapper for each subfolder. I notice in your updated code, you have only one subfolder file wrapper. With only one subfolder file wrapper, you have no way to store an image file in the correct subfolder.

To add the images, start by converting each image into a `Data` object. Create a regular file wrapper for each image, passing the image data as the argument to `regularFileWithContents`. Call `addFileWrapper` to add the image file to the appropriate folder.

```
let imageFile = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: imageData)
imageFile.preferredFilename = "ImageFilename" // Replace with your filename.
imagesWrapper.addFileWrapper(imageFile)
```

In your case the image subfolders will call `addFileWrapper` to add the images. The destination for the image file calls `addFileWrapper`.

You can find more detailed information about file wrappers in the following article:

[Using File Wrappers in a SwiftUI App](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/using-file-wrappers-in-a-swiftui-app/)

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the correct answer. One more question, I don't really get how I can put my image in the correct subfolder?

Let's say my images folder has these subfolders: 1, 2, 3. How can I write my images to a specific folder using imageSubFolder.addRegularFile(withContents: image, preferredFilename: name)?

Comment: I've updated my post with code ho I do it now. But now I get an error:

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <NSConcreteHashTable: 0x600002f06440> was mutated while being enumerated.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Call `imageSubFolder.addFileWrapper` to put your image in the correct subfolder, replacing imageSubFolder with the variable name for the subfolder. I don't have a specific answer for your exception problem. I recommend creating an exception breakpoint by choosing Debug > Breakpoints > Create Exception Breakpoint. Xcode will stop at the place in the code where the app crashes.

Comment: Still not really getting the hang of it. I’m now able to create the subfolders. And I fixed the exception. But how do I write images to these folders? I don’t think is a good idea to create a variable of an array of Data, as this would take a lot of memory. But now I’m still having the problem that my images get deleted when saving the file. Probably because I’m still directly writing the data to the url, and not via a FileWrapper. I just don’t get how to write images to these subfolders

Comment: Sorry for my unexperience in this area. There’s just not a lot of documentation and examples for what I need. I get how a static file work. It just loads the data to a variable in the FileDocument. But for these subfolders, and their contents, I kind of reaching in the dark. Hope you can help me out! :)

Comment: You write images to the folders by converting the images to `Data` objects, creating a regular file wrapper for each image, and having the folder call `addFileWrapper` to add the image to the folder. Pretty much everything I know about file wrappers is in my answer and the article I linked to in the answer. Look at the `FileWrapper` class documentation for additional information on file wrappers.